# How to simulate short circuit and in opencv

Tags: python, c++, opencv, bitwise-and

I am trying to check whether a binary image (template) is contained inside another image (source). To do that, I first started doing something like this:

(its a pseudo code resembling python, but I'm more interested in the right technique than in the language implementation)

```
#this code runs once at startup
template_nonzero = count_nonzero(template)

#this code is run inside a function
mask = bitwise_and(template, source)
is_contained = count_nonzero(mask) == template_nonzero
```

Then I realized I could speed things up by avoiding count_nonzero:

```
mask = bitwise_and(template, source)
mask_against_template = bitwise_xor(template, mask)
is_contained = not mask_against_template.any()
```

This code is almost 3 times faster than the first one. I'm now wondering if there is such a thing as a short circuit and operator in opencv that would return true if bitwise_and is true for all white pixels or false upon finding the first false operation. This way I wouldnt have to use xor or even run through the entire image in a bitwise_and.

Any ideas?

Edit:

I forgot to mention that I even tried this code, but using xor is a bit faster than using ==:

```
mask = bitwise_and(template, source)
mask_against_template = template == mask
is_contained = mask_against_template.all()
```

Comment: As far as I know, OpenCV does not have anything like that, but you can use  std::find_if with cv::Mat iterators and a predicate that returns true when your condition is met(in this case that a pixel is not white). It will stop at the first True value and it will only check the image once. If all are white it will return iterator end, which you can compare after it finishes it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up finding a solution. I implemented the short-circuit and operation in python which turned out to be a lot slower than the cv2.bitwise_and followed by a cv2.bitwise_xor. But then I used numba to pre compile that function and I ended up having a function that runs 4x as fast as the cv2 one. Here's the code:

```
@numba.jit("b1(u1[:,:],u1[:,:])")
def is_template_in(template, image):
    for y in range(0, template.shape[0]):
        for x in range(0, template.shape[1]):
            if template[y][x] and not image[y][x]:
                return False
    return True
```